# react-router-dom refresh component when route changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I used same component for different routes. When route changes, I want the component to be rendered.

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
    <Route path="/hotels" component={HotelsPage} />
    <Route path="/apartments" component={HotelsPage} />
</Switch>
```

When I change the route path from `/hotels` to `/apartments`, the component `HotelsPage` doesn't refresh.

What is the cool approach for this?

Comment: one of the way : `<Route path="/hotels" component={props => <HotelsPage {...props} />} />`

Comment: Component won't refresh until and unless it's props are changes. You need to explicitly pass props to the component.

Comment: Thanks guys. It solved the problem. However, how can I scroll screen top when route changes? :)

Comment: Did you mean once your route is changed you want to scroll to the top ? I have posted it as a answer if it did solved your problem mentioned above , please accept the answer :)

Comment: Yeah, never mind. I've solved it myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the ways you can get this sorted is by passing the props explicitly like :

`<Route path="/hotels" component={props => <HotelsPage {...props} />} />`

Comment: Well, though this solved initial problem, it refreshes the component when redux prop changes. I want it to refresh only when route changes.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: without seeing the code its not possible to tell you the right solution , And the above solution was according to your above question (which shows no signs of redux)

Answer (score 5):

Firstly you can aggregate the Route into one like

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
    <Route path="/(hotels|apartments)" component={HotelsPage} />
</Switch>
```

and secondly, your `HotelsPage` component is rendered both on `/hotels`, `/apartments`, it is similar case like path params, whereby the component doesn't mount again on path change, but updates thereby calling `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle function,

What you can do is implement `componentWillReceiveProps` like

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.location.pathname !== this.props.location.pathname) {
      console.log("here");
      //take action here
    }
  }
```

[**DEMO**](https://codesandbox.io/s/lpwmq4k94l)

Comment: Yes, could you describe "action"? Can I reload the whole component there not partial states or props?

Comment: What do you mean by reloading the whole component

Comment: Like when you refresh the browser.

Comment: This is by far the best approach, since you can just re-render components, within the page component, thereby not loading the whole page component again.

Answer (score 0):

I guess just passing `useLocation().pathname` will resolve issue

```
  useEffect(
    () => {
         // Your logics
        });
    }, [useLocation().pathname])
```